# how to enable webex on 14.10 64bits

Tags: firefox, java

I had issues to join Cisco Webex in Firefox on 14.10 64bits. Here is my experience to make it work.

First, you need to install either openjdk/icedtea or Oracle Java as the JRE.

You should be able find plenty of tutorials to enable Java for Firefox. openjdk/icedtea is the easier. Here is the issue that I met for Oracle Java.

When Cisco Webex java app runs in Firefox, there is a security warning blocking you to run it. The publisher and the web site is displayed in the warning page.

To solve it, you need to run "javaws" from the command line and then change option to enable the Java app.

For Oracle Java 1.7, you may change the security level from "High" to "Medium". It increases risk, of course. The recommended way is to add the web site into the "Exception Site List", which is also under "Security" tab. However, I had some difficult to find the correct URL for my Webex web site, so I used the non-recommended way.

Oracle Java 1.8 doesn't have "Medium" security option and "Exception Site List" should work.

After Java is enable successfully, I am able to join a Webex (I see a new Webex window with meeting info, like participants ...) but I still cannot see the shared desktop from the host.

This is caused by missing 32bits C/C++ shared libraries which are needed by Webex libraries. Webex libraries are stored in $HOME/.webex/. "ldd ..." command will show you what's missing and you should install these extra package. This is the command to list missing libraries.

```
cd $HOME/.webex/<a_4_digit_number_folder_name>
ldd *.so | grep "not found"
```

You should be able to find some web page talking about this issue on other version of Ubuntu. For 14.10, there are some packages cannot be found from regular Ubuntu repositories and Debian packages are your friend.

In my case, there are 2 shared libraries cannot be found, especially that I am on a 64 bits system and the needed libraries are 32bits.

I need both packages libgcj and libgcj-awt for i386. I download them from the following link and install them from Ubuntu Software Centre (libgcj14 first then libgcj14-awt).

```
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgcj14_4.8.4-1_i386.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgcj14-awt_4.8.4-1_i386.deb
```

After installing, "ldd ..." still shows missing libraries even I do have these libraries under /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/

I tried these without luck
    cd $HOME/.webex/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so

Then I add "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/" into a config file under "/etc/ld.so.conf.d" then I run "ldconfig". No luck.

Finally, I did the following trick, then no more missing library and I see the shared desktop.

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so .
```

By the way, I also tried Chrome without luck either. Java cannot enabled in my case and internet search tells me it's a known issue.

Good luck with your experience on Webex.